# Не получается реализовать метод contains();

Tags: java

Подскажите в чем ошибка не получается реализовать метод contains();
Метод должен проверять есть ли переданный в параметры элемент в TreeLinkedSet

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class TreeLinkedSet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            private Container cursor;

            {
                if (root != null) {
                    cursor = passLeft(root);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return cursor != null;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                T res = cursor.val;
                if (cursor.right != null) {
                    cursor = passLeft(cursor.right);

                } else if (cursor.right == null) {
                    cursor = passBack(cursor);
                }
                return res;
            }

        };
    }

    private class Container implements Comparable<Container> {

        private Container left;
        private Container right;
        private Container prior;
        private T val;

        public Container(T val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Container o) {
            return val.compareTo(o.val);
        }

    }
    private Container root;
    private int size;

    public int Size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void add(T t) {
        Container c = new Container(t);
        if (root == null) {
            root = c;
            size++;
        } else {
            choose(root, c);

        }
    }

    private void choose(Container base, Container c) {
        if (c.compareTo(base) < 0) {
            if (base.left == null) {
                base.left = c;
                c.prior = base;
                size++;
            } else {
                choose(base.left, c);
            }
        }
        if (c.compareTo(base) > 0) {
            if (base.right == null) {
                base.right = c;
                c.prior = base;
                size++;
            } else {
                choose(base.right, c);
            }
        }
    }

    private Container passLeft(Container c) {
        return c.left == null ? c : passLeft(c.left);
    }

    private Container passBack(Container c) {
        if (c.prior != null) {
            return c.prior.compareTo(c) > 0 ? c.prior : passBack(c.prior);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public T[] toArray(T[] type) {
        T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
        int i = 0;
        for (T t : this) {
            res[i++] = t;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public T first() {
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Container maxLeft = root;
        while (maxLeft.left != null) {
            maxLeft = maxLeft.left;
        }
        return maxLeft.val;
    }

    public T last() {
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Container maxRight = root;
        while (maxRight.right != null) {
            maxRight = maxRight.right;
        }
        return maxRight.val;
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (root != null) {
            root = null;
            size = 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (root.equals(o)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        if (c != null) {
            for (T t : c) {
                add(t);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Реализация подобна методам `first/last`.
Т.е. проходимся от корня до концов, пока не найдём.

```
public boolean contains(T o) {
    Container current;
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }
    current = root;
    do { // ищем вправо от корня
      if (current.val.equals(o)) return true;
      current = current.right;
    } while (current != null)

    current = root;
    do { // ищем влево от корня
      if (current.val.equals(o)) return true;
      current = current.left;
    } while (current != null)

    return false;
}
```